# Formatting problem with PHP DateTime Difference when used as part of an equation

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to write a simple invoicing system. I wanted to use DateTime Diff to calculate the cost of each invoice.

So far I have:

```
/* In this example $dayLength and $ratePerSec don't really matter but we will use the 
   hypotethical values of 8.0 and 0.0054 for now */

$date1 = new DateTime( "Time1FromDatabase", [DateTimeZoneOfChoice] );
$date2 = new DateTime( "Time2FromDatabase", [DateTimeZoneOfChoice] );

$diff = $date2->diff( $date1 );
$lenInSec = $diff->format("%y")*365*$dayLength*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%d")*$dayLength*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%h")*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%i")*60 + 
            $diff->format("%s");

$cost = $lenInSec * $ratePerSecond;
```

When I try to output cost using the $lenInSec generated from DateTime Diff I get really odd results.
Sometimes, anywhere from 1 in 3 and 1 in 50 times, I get the correct value of say 460.25. A lot of the time I just get a random string of letters, numbers or symbols, such as: þ50.

I've found that if I echo out the result 2+ times then on the final output I get the expected result perfectly.

My temporary fix at the moment is, in the getCost() function, to run:

```
ob_start();
echo $cost;
echo $cost;
ob_clean();
return $cost;
```

And so far this seems to fix the problem and I seem to get the expected result every time but it's a bit weird.

I know it's the DateTime Diff in the equation because if I replace it with the old-style:

```
strtotime( "Time2FromDatabase") - strtotime( "Time1FromDatabase")
```

it works perfectly every time.

I also have a running total cost:

```
$totalCost += $cost;
```

Outputting $totalCost always outputs the correct value regardless of whether I use the DateTime Diff method or the strtotime method.

I've also tried using intval. (int) and (string) casts on the $lenInSec variable before using it in the equation and it has no effect.

Can anyone give any clues as to why this is happening? Is it a(n) (un)known bug in PHP's DateTime/Diff classes?

EDIT:

```
$date1 = new DateTime( "2011-09-04 09:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC") );
$date2 = new DateTime( "2011-09-04 18:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC") );

//Essentially 1 day of work

$rate = 200.00; //Per Day
$ratePerSec = 0.00617283950617283950617283950617; 
// $rate / (9 hours * 3600 seconds )

$lenInSec = 32400; // From the diff calculation

$cost = $lenInSec * $ratePerSec; // Cost should now equal 200. 

echo $cost; // Sometimes outputs 8, other times 200, other times þ50.

//I think the þ50 is when you have a number like 425.50 where þ is the 425.

$totalCost += $cost;

echo number_format($totalCost,2); /* Will return the correct 
value of all the $cost variables added no matter what the individual $cost 
variables are output as, in this case 200.00 */
```

Comment: Are you sure that the used datetime formats are the same? Try using the `DateTime::createFromFormat()` method. Other than that ... except you can replace the `%y` and `%d` with `%a`(for total days) I don't think that there's anything wrong on your part. There are a number of warnings for inacurracies in the user comments for `DateTime::diff()`, and since this is a relatively new extension for PHP - I guess it could be a bug.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll give your suggestions a try and report back. Although I'm pretty sure they DateTime formats are the same. They both come from a datetime field in a Mysql database.

Comment: CreateFromFormat() didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: I meant the format fetched from the database compared to the default one accepted by PHP's DateTime.

Comment: @Narf: Your first comment should probably be an answer. :)

Comment: Could you supply some sample input and _expected_ output Along with the _wrong_ output you're receiving?

Comment: I've updated my question as requested.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. $cost is ALWAYS equal to $rate because `$ratePerSec = $rate / $lenInSec` and `$cost = $lenInSec * $ratePerSec = $rate`. Furthermore, there's nothing in the code you provided that should EVER cause it to output þ or 8. In my tests I set `$totalCost = 0` and `$dayLength = 9` and had no problems even when changing `$rate = 425.50`. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: In this example $cost is the same as $rate. If you took:
2011-09-10 09:00:00 and 2011-09-10 13:00:00 then you would get 88.88. All I can tell you is that as soon as I replace the DateTime Diff with a strtotime() subtraction the formatting errors disappear. I also meant that when $cost = 425.50 (from the calculation, say at a length of 2 days and 3 hours ) I get the þ.50.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this is not a bug in the DateTime class. More likely, it stems from somewhere else in your code.

Working from the code snippets you supplied and your comments, I produced this:

```php
$totalCost = 0; // uninitialized in your sample code, potential source of problem
$dayLength = 9;
$rate = 425.50;

$ratePerSecond = $rate / ($dayLength * 3600);

// 2 days, 3 hours
$date1 = new DateTime( "2011-09-10 09:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC") );
$date2 = new DateTime( "2011-11-10 12:00:00", new DateTimeZone("UTC") );

$diff = $date2->diff( $date1 );
$lenInSec = $diff->format("%y")*365*$dayLength*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%d")*$dayLength*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%h")*3600 + 
            $diff->format("%i")*60 + 
            $diff->format("%s");

$cost = $lenInSec * $ratePerSecond;

$totalCost += $cost;

echo number_format($totalCost,2);
```

which **always** yields `141.83`.

You’re really not providing enough code or a *concrete* example that produces the formatting problem. Nothing *in the code you provided* should ever result in a random string of letters, numbers or symbols.

Comment: Basically I had a script that was ~1000 lines long for generating the whole invoice. Through trial & error I found the cost calc code to be the problem. I made a new file with JUST the cost calc code in it which is the ~11 lines of code I have given here. I ran that script with hardcoded values to make sure it wasn't a problem elsewhere and I still have the problem. I don't see how giving you more code will help when this is the min. required to produce the problem. The only other possibility left, if not the DateTime classes is my server settings but I don't know what settings would do this.

Comment: OK so I just ran the code on my live server (about 50 times) and it does return the correct value every time. Do you have any idea what might be causing this problem in my testing server (Xampplite 1.7.3)?

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem with anything you've given. You might try turning error reporting on (if it's not already) and see if anything jumps out. _I suspect one of your variables is being treated as a string rather than a number._ Since several variables are uninitialized in the code snippets you provided, I have to assume they're initialized elsewhere. That _could_ be contributing to the problem. I'm sorry. I wish I could be more helpful.